# React, animating individual photos as you scroll down with framer motion and intersection observer

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I'm trying to use intersection observer to track if items are in view or not and framer motion for the animation. I'm trying to have each individual photo be animated into view when you scroll down to that specific one. Instead what's happening is the whole container and all the photos (which are blog posts when clicked on) are animating into view as one when you can see the first one.

If I pass the ref inside of map(), in the BlogCardContainer I get the same effect but it only does the animation when I reach the last post, above the last post the photos are off the screen.

So I believe the problem is I'm listening to the gallery container with ref so when I reach that on scroll it brings everything in with it but if I listen to each card it only listens for the last one then brings everything in with it. If anyone knows how to fix that or get around it I'd appreciate any feedback.

useEffect, useInView from intersection observer, and animation from framer motion hooks are below

```
const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    threshold: 0.05
  });
  const animation = useAnimation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(inView) {
      animation.start({
        x: 0,
        transition: {
          type: 'spring', duration: 1, bounce: 0.5
        }
      });
    }
    if(!inView) {
        animation.start({ x: '-100vw' })
      }
  }, [inView]);
```

Here's the return statement

```
return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <LoaderContainer>
          <RingLoader />
        </LoaderContainer>
        ) : (
        <GalleryContainer ref={ref}>
      {allPostsData &&
        allPostsData.map((post, index) => (
          <BlogCardsContainer key={post.slug.current}>
            <motion.div animate={animation} >
              <BlogLink to={"/" + post.slug.current}>
                <BlogCards src={urlFor(post.mainImage.asset.url).url()} alt={post.title} />
                <BlogCardTitle>{post.title}</BlogCardTitle>
              </BlogLink>
            </motion.div>
          </BlogCardsContainer>
          
        ))}
      </GalleryContainer>
        )}
      
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want without using the Intersection Observer API. Framer Motion provides Scroll Animations (https://www.framer.com/docs/scroll-animations/), so you may want to take a look at the Scroll Trigger section.

In any case, the trick for me was creating a separate component and including the motion.div and the logic there. Then, you can map your array passing the neccesary props to that component. You don't even need useRef or useEffect!

Something like this:

```js
return (
  <>
    {isLoading ? (
      <LoaderContainer>
        <RingLoader />
      </LoaderContainer>
    ) : (
      <GalleryContainer>
        {allPostsData &&
          allPostsData.map((post, index) => (
            <MyAnimatedComponent post={post} />
          ))}
      </GalleryContainer>
    )}
  </>
);
```

And then in the component:

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export const MyAnimatedComponent = (props) => {
  const { post } = props;

  return (
    <BlogCardsContainer key={post.slug.current}>
      <motion.div
        initial={{ x: 0 }}
        whileInView={{ x: -100 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
        transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0.5, duration: 1 }}
      >
        <BlogLink to={"/" + post.slug.current}>
          <BlogCards
            src={urlFor(post.mainImage.asset.url).url()}
            alt={post.title}
          />
          <BlogCardTitle>{post.title}</BlogCardTitle>
        </BlogLink>
      </motion.div>
    </BlogCardsContainer>
  );
};
```